# How to check how many parallel XMLHttpRequests are uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've read that it depends on your browser how many parallel XMLHttpRequests are allowed. But I want to check browser-independent how many XMLHttpRequests are uploading because I want to create a process bar: current progress=evt.loaded/evt.total works only for active XMLHttpRequests. but if the count of XMLHttpRequests is bigger than the currently allowed the progress bar makes no sense that way so I want to know how to get the current XMLHttpRequests to a javascript variable. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but there's nothing built-in to do it. Keep a count yourself.

Comment: Ah ok! What a shame that there is nothing built in :( But thanks! But if you got some tips or keywords to look for for me please feel free to write another comment ;)

Comment: `var count = 0` somewhere, then increase it before an ajax request, and decrease it in the success. you won't find this anywhere online because it's too simple.

Comment: yeah you are right. That's really simple. :D Thanks again!